# Create Tree Structure from Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

I have an array like this:

```
array(
      array(id => 7, parent_id => 0, name => Current Assets)
      array(id => 8, parent_id => 0, name => Fixed Assets)
      array(id => 18, parent_id => 7, name => Assets)
      array(id => 38, parent_id => 18, name => Receivable)
      array(id => 38, parent_id => 18, name => Inventory)
      array(id => 39, parent_id => 0, name => Landed Cost Of Inventory)
      array(id => 40, parent_id => 38, name => Jazz Cash)
      array(id => 41, parent_id => 39, name => Advance to Vendors)
)
```

Now I need some efficient way to convert this into tree structure like this.

```
array(
      array(id => 7, parent_id => 0, name => Current Assets, level=>0)
      array(id => 8, parent_id => 0, name => Fixed Asset, level => )
      array(id => 18, parent_id => 7, name => Assets, level => 1)
      array(id => 38, parent_id => 18, name => Inventory, level => 2)
      array(id => 39, parent_id => 0, name => Landed Cost Of Inventory, level => 0)
      array(id => 40, parent_id => 38, name => Jazz Cash, level => 3)
      array(id => 41, parent_id => 39, name => Advance to Vendors, level => 1)
)
```

I no need to add them left or right, I just need the simple levels that I will pass to jQgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect all ids in the order of `parent -> child` in an array where `parent_id` is the key and it has an array of all child IDs. Second step is to just traverse the tree and assign the ranks.

```
<?php

function assignLevels(&$data){
    $kids = [];

    foreach($data as $d){
        $kids[ $d['parent_id'] ] = $kids[ $d['parent_id'] ] ?? [];
        $kids[ $d['parent_id'] ][] = $d['id'];
    }
    
    $data = array_column($data, null, 'id');
    traverseTree($kids, 0, $data);
    $data = array_values($data);
}


function traverseTree($kids, $id, &$data, $level = 0){
    foreach($kids[ $id ] as $sub_id){
        $data[ $sub_id ]['level'] = $level;
        if(isset($kids[ $sub_id ] )) traverseTree($kids, $sub_id, $data, $level + 1);
    }
}

assignLevels($data);

print_r($data);
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f12cc02d4eb760551bf9f4784e12742fd0ded00f)

Comment: It only creat up to level 1, like see here
Array ( [id] => 29 [parent_id] => 23 [name] => Output Tax [hasChild] => 1 [parent_name] => [value] => 15480 [level] => 1 )
Array ( [id] => 31 [parent_id] => 29 [name] => Sales tax (Output) [hasChild] => 0 [parent_name] => [value] => 120000 [level] => 1 )

level of array id 31 should be 2

Comment: @TahirLilla Can you var_export() and paste the input array here?

Comment: 0: {id: '7', parent_id: '0', name: 'Current Assets', value: 16000, level: 0}
1: {id: '39', parent_id: '23', name: 'Advance from Customers', value: 0, level: 1}
2: {id: '42', parent_id: '15', name: 'Cost- Wallpaper', value: 0, level: 1}
3: {id: '35', parent_id: '15', name: 'Carbonated Drink Cost', value: 0, level: 1}
4: {id: '16', parent_id: '0', name: 'Operating Expenses', value: 0, level: 0}
5: {id: '15', parent_id: '0', name: 'Cost of Good Sold', value: 0, level: 0}

Comment: 16: {id: '29', parent_id: '23', name: 'Output Tax', value: 15480, level: 1}

Comment: I think my array is not sorted as a parent first

Comment: @TahirLilla See my updated answer. It should work now.

Comment: it worked! i just sort array and then pass it , Thanks

Comment: @TahirLilla Glad it worked, but avoid sorting.. Use the above code as is..

Comment: What if i want to add types in array, like type_id 1, name Assects all rows which comes under this type, save under Type name array or something like this.....?

Comment: @TahirLilla Didn't follow. Could you post your requirement as a new question?